# Single-point ground vs multi-point ground - large DC system

Tags: power, grounding, cables, star

So we're working on a DC system with little space for cabling and a size which requires at most 1.5m cable length. We're running power on 48V DC (hence, frequency = 0) with a max of about 5Amps per device connected.
There are 4 devices connected along the 1.5M.

We desire a multi-point ground system such that we could run just a single power line rather than a power line for each device which belongs to a single-point grounding system.

After doing some reading in 'Noise reduction techniques in electronic systems' by Henry W. Ott, we can conclude that it's best for us to still run a single-point ground system but this trade-off does require us to run more cables.

Is this trade-off worth the space needed in a interference-sensitive system? We do run seperate data-communications between the devices as well.

What could be good arguments for both or makes one topology significantly more wise to implement? I'm very curious about the technical aspects as well, makes me learn a lot!

I drew a picture to show the single-point system vs the multi-point system.
[image]

Edit: I added an image that shows not only power, but also (digital) communication lines. As you might notice, this has shielding which is connected to (common) ground at one single point such that noise will not find a gnd path over data.
[image]

I drew only 3 devices, but in fact, there are four with all the same power requirements.

Comment: Do the different blocks send analog signals to each other, or is it all digital between blocks?

Comment: Digital communications

Comment: Show the digital interconnections too.

Comment: For the 3 devices shown the topology is identical. Is one of the four devices different (e.g. much lower power) so that you could afford a separate cable for it?

Comment: edited with an additional drawing

Comment: What do you mean by "interference-sensitive"?  Is this a low level analog/RF system with digital communications between the boxes you drew?  Or is a purely digital?

Comment: I don't have my Ott book handy, but I believe that he also says never to run single ended digital signals from box to box.

Comment: @Mattman944 would appreciate the page, then i could dig into that! thanks!

Comment: @Mattman94- "never to run single ended digital signals from box to box" is one our basic digital design guidelines.

Comment: Yet, i'm curious about the meaning of 'single-ended'. Does this mean shielding connected at one single end?

Comment: @Mart - single-ended: one logic output to one logic input. The shielding diagrams in Ott's book are mostly for analog signals. For digital, you want a low-inductance return path. You should connect your shields at both ends, not to the single point ground. You should draw more of your system for us to evaluate (probably another question, old questions don't get much attention). Also, if current is flowing in your ground connections (power return path), you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In either situation, one device could be taking a large current and producing a significant (and noisy) volt drop down its return wire. If the return wire (at the device) is also a reference node for digital comms, then there would be chance that some device load currents can also flow through the comms interconnections and cause havoc with data. The noisy device currents would not take this route if there wasn't a volt drop of course.

So, the comms are potentially likely to suffer without some form of galvanic isolation or, a comms system with a high level of common-mode noise resilience. Whichever you choose you need to stop noisy device currents partially flowing back via a route that they are not intended to follow.

All the above words are about trying to keep your comms data intact. As for power, individual cables might be better but once you have the comms problem sorted any method would work providing that you do what I suggest for the comms and, at a risk of boring you I'll repeat/add: -

- Galvanic isolation
- Differential signalling
- High common-mode resilience

Comment: You'll not bore me, instead, the more detail the better. Like i said, i'm here to learn and so are most of the users here!

Answer (score -1):

To better clean up the GROUND wiring, use 1,000uF and 1 Ohm resistors on the DC wiring of each module.

This --- Local Battery mindset --- supplies all the fast transient charges needed within each module.

The 1 ohm greatly reduces the transient interaction between stages, and the 1 OHM is required.

Comment: 1 ohm * 5 amps?